# SVG rotate path

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm starting to use SVG and so far it's all okay, but when I try to do some animation with CSS the result isn't what I expect it to be.

I want to rotate a gear like in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJku3/1/).

Below is the CSS I used to rotate the elements:

```
.gear {
    -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotation {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-moz-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes rotation {
    from {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-o-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
@keyframes rotation {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to rotate gear from svg like gear from img @JoshC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) to `50% 50%` in order to make the `svg` animation function like the `img` one:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YEA7T/)

```
.gear {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

It's worth noting that the default/initial value of the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property is `50% 50% 0`.

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-origin-property (the reason why transform-origin is not `50% 50%` in svg per default is because `transform` was not a property in SVG 1.1. It would break lots of existing svg content unless the `transform-origin` default was `0 0`).

Comment: It should be noted, this is not consistent between Chrome and Firefox. In FF, the rotation center is still in the top left of the canvas.

Comment: Seems to be broken now: 50% is calculated from the whole svg, not just this path. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add this tag inside your `svg` tag to rotate it around it's center:

```
<animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="360 0 0" to="0 0 0" dur="9s" additive="sum" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is animated in Chromium at least. Just the center is not correct. (Try to remove the width, height and x/y attributes, while just using the viewBox for the SVG tag.)

In Opera I could get it working, when setting the class "gear" to the SVG element instead of the path:

```
<svg class="gear" …
```

[You may also have to set the `transform-origin`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)