# I need help rotating an svg element in my logo

Tags: html, css, svg, css-transforms

**I want my initials "CND" to rotate like this:**

http://jsfiddle.net/rukC6/1/

HTML:

```
<head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <img src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTCKie7zNcXtCeCjnMsE8kyg7D9fC_-Hllk7VaNoXIGHPLxbWP" class="animation-rotate"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
  25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
  45% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  70% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); }
  75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.animation-rotate {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4.5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

**but my code is making it rotate around a wide circle instead of staying in the center:**

http://codepen.io/CaptnChristiana/pen/hCsHn

HTML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="399" height="378" viewBox="0 0 399 378"><style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#15ADBC;stroke-width:3;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:#15ADBC;stroke:#15ADBC;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st3{fill:none;stroke:#1D1E1E;stroke-width:8;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}]]></style>

  <path class="st1" d="M99.972 180.794l175.591 58.929-123.703 85.748zM45.64 210.785l59.428-127.262-5.096 97.271-54.332 29.991 106.22 114.686 174.202-31.196M105.385 82.349l128.825.633-134.238 97.812M308.37 154.665l17.692 139.61-50.499-54.552 32.807-85.058-73.179-71.466.12 2.235 40.252 154.289"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="105.385" cy="82.349" r="3.263"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="235.191" cy="83.199" r="3.263"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="308.349" cy="154.892" r="3.263"/>
  <path class="st2" d="M329.321 294.1c.097 1.799-1.284 3.336-3.084 3.434-1.8.096-3.336-1.283-3.433-3.082-.098-1.803 1.283-3.338 3.082-3.434 1.801-.098 3.339 1.281 3.435 3.082z"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="151.861" cy="325.471" r="3.263"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="46.478" cy="209.807" r="3.263"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="99.973" cy="180.795" r="3.263"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="275.564" cy="239.723" r="3.264"/>
  <g class="initials">
    <path class="st3" d="M233.525 239.931c4.9.225 10.302-.09 15.021-1.492 14.457-4.304 24.611-19.246 26.432-33.729 1.84-14.646-6.16-28.656-18.408-36.203-15.918-9.807-31.015-3.852-31.015-3.852l-19.523 97.735-25.52-117.075-19.141 93.81c-15.568 4.092-30.443.303-41.066-12.182-14.854-17.457-6.279-37.685-6.279-37.685 11.439-27.958 38.459-25.105 38.459-25.105"/></g></svg>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
  25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
  45% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  70% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); }
  75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.initials {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4.5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;

}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394547/svg-rotate-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [**`transform-origin`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property to `50% 50%`:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ncxsm)

```
.st3 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

It's worth noting that the initial/default value of the [**`transform-origin`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property is `50% 50% 0`.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much. Is there a way to make it animate when you hover over my logo? I know "hover" needs to be put somewhere in the CSS but I'm not sure where.

Comment: @ChristianaDelVecchio See [this updated example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EHpnr)