# Rotating SVG CSS Animation in Firefox Not Working, and Need SVG Fallbacks

Tags: css, xml, svg, cross-browser, css-animations

I'm trying to animate these gears, and it works as intended in Chrome. However, in Firefox the rotation origin is different, and can't figure out how to fix this.

I've tried playing with the width, height, viewbox, and x & y attributes, but nothing seems to work perfectly.

Based on the [SVG rotate path example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394547/svg-rotate-path).

And finally, what would be best practice for providing proper fallbacks for my SVG paths in other/older browsers that will not support my graphic/animation?

**The rest of the code is here: [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/colleenroxas/xnztbygf/)**
(HTML + SVG code was too long to paste)

**CSS:**

```
#gear-head {
  position: fixed;
  background: #172235;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#gear-head .gear {
  -webkit-animation: rotation 6s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: rotation 6s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: rotation 6s infinite linear;
  animation: rotation 6s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
#gear-head .pulsating {
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 6s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Firefox does not yet support transform-origin on SVG elements where the transform-origin units are percentages. Change the units or stop using transform-origin altogether to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use half-height and half-width units:

instead of transform-origin: 50% 50%;

get the width and height of your svg (ex: width="234px" height="186px"); divide both values by 2 (to get 117px and 93px, respectively); then use

transform-origin: 117px 93px;

this should work on all browsers (I only tested on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox)